# SELECT BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + 365

Tags: mysql, date

Im trying to write a SQL script to retrieve dates between a set range. The statement below does work, however doesn't retrieve all the correct data within the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `column` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + 365
```

Comment: What makes you say its not retrieving "all the correct data"? We can't see your data, so we can't see what's missing either!

Comment: Do you really want 365 days, and not 1 year? There are those nasty leap years.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `column` BETWEEN curdate() AND curdate() + interval 365 day
```

Comment: It is better to be `... + interval 1 year`. Because sometimes there are 366 days.

Comment: Probably yes. But not knowing the use case of the OP we can't say for sure this is the intended behaviour. For instance if I want to delete all entries older than 30 days then I do not want to use a month instead, since February has only 28 days.

Comment: bit of a punt, but is there a way of amending the script to SELECT * until the end of the current year???

Comment: @LukeHiggins: `where year(column) = year(curdate())`

Comment: I think this is bad idea. What if `curdate()` is 01.December? Only 31 days for the query instead of 365? If you need only current year, you can simply change the condition to `BETWEEN curdate() and CONCAT(LEFT(curdate(),5),'12-31')`.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + interval 1 year